# CURL Error 28 from one site to another - Looking for solutions or workarounds

Tags: wordpress, curl

I am running this very basic code from my client's site:

```
$url  = 'https://my-site......com';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

And I receive the CURL error 28 no matter what.

I have tried to increase the timeout, to no avail. The CURLOPT_VERBOSE gives no information to backtrace the issue.

It works well the other way around: from my site to the client's site.

Both sites are fresh Wordpress installs, no plugins, default theme.

I have spent *months* with the support of both webhosts, each have made all the possible tests on their side, and cannot identify the origin of the issue. My site is hosted at Siteground. This problem occurs almost always when the customer's site is hosted at OVH, but I have also observed this problem once with Gandi and once with Loopia.

The problem sometimes resolves by itself after few months, or on the contrary, it sometimes occurs after properly working for months.

**I am looking for any kind of help**:

- how to identify the origin of the issue
- a solution
- a workaround

I got to the point of setting up a server in between that just forwards the request and the response:

- Request:  client's site > proxy > my site
- Response: my site > proxy > client's site

But I need to use that proxy only for one specific request sent with [wp_remote_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/), I don't know if this is possible and how to do it.